# How can I manage to split the int value in C#

Tags: c#

[For this int has the value of "19971998". I really wanted to split this value into like this "1997 - 1998"!?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VloE5.png)

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(radioListBox1.SelectedIndex);
string indexvalue = Convert.ToString(this.radioListBox1.Items[index]);
string input = Regex.Replace(indexvalue, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);
MessageBox.Show(input);
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  From the image, I can see you are trying so please post the code you've tried and explain what trouble you're having.

Comment: It would be great if you included the code in the question post itself and also applied the code formatting to it.

Comment: `if (indexvalue.Length == 8) indexvalue = indexvalue.Insert(4, " - ");` or perhaps `indexvalue = indexvalue.Insert(indexvalue.Length/2, " - ");`

Comment: Thank you Sir, you did resolved my problem.

Comment: Please get out of the habit of storing data in the UI; you should store data in its native format and include references or something to the native data in the UI. This is going to save you many headaches in the future.

Comment: What if the int has the value of "199719989" or more than 8 length value of the int. How can I manage to remove the last int value, which is this one "9" or else!?

Comment: @AngeloCuevasOngue You can take just the first 8 characters if it's longer than 8 by using `if (indexValue.Length > 8) indexValue = indexValue.Substring(0, 8);` before doing the `indexvalue = indexvalue.Insert(indexvalue.Length/2, " - ");`

Answer (score 1):

you can write like :

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(radioListBox1.SelectedIndex);
string indexvalue = Convert.ToString(this.radioListBox1.Items[index]);
string input = Regex.Replace(indexvalue, ".{4}", "$0-");
MessageBox.Show(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "19971998";
String.Format("{0}-{1}", s.Substring(0,4), s.Substring(4, 4)));
```

Comment: What if the int has the value of "199719989" or more than 8 length value of the int. How can I manage to remove the last int value, which is this one "9" or else!?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work with `Regex` you'd need to do the following:

```
string input = Regex.Replace(indexvalue, "^(.{4})", "$1-");
```

But as someone suggested, it may be even easier to do this one.

```
string input = indexvalue.Insert(4, "-");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(radioListBox1.SelectedIndex);
    string indexvalue = Convert.ToString(this.radioListBox1.Items[index]);
    string input = Regex.Replace(indexvalue, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);
```

> **The problem was solved, this was missing my code.**

```
    if (input.Length == 8) input = input.Insert(4, " - ");

    MessageBox.Show(input);
```